# converting a csv file to a list of list without any library with keeping some of columns

Tags: python, excel, database, list, csv

I have a csv file with 4 columns like this:

ID,Make,Model,Year

33527,BMW,3 Series Gran Turismo,2018

5335,Ford,F-150,1990

458,Toyota,Camry,1994

14565,Toyota,Camry,1998

...

...

...

I want to convert this csv to a list of list "without use of any library or import".

I want the result to be a list of list and only with columns 1, 2 and 4 like this:

[[33527,BMW,2018] , [5335,Ford,1990] , [458,Toyota,1994]  , [14565,Toyota,1998],....]

how should I make this list of list without help of any library?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read the file line by line.  For each line `split` on the delimiter, and do what you want with the resulting list.  This is just basic Python - file read, string split, list comprehensions and list appends.  Practice with the simplest processing, and then add complications one by one.

Comment: You should explain the reason for not using *any library or import*. Anyway the answer is trivial: just mimic what the csv library does. You can even relax the support for corner cases (new line or separators in fields) if your input file is simple enough...

Comment: BTW, do you accept to use string methods like split? And reading a file without using `open` from the standard library could be impossible...

Comment: `[[c for i, c in enumerate(s.strip().split(",")) if i != 2] for s in open("temp.csv")]` *(it's just demonstration, [better to use `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to open file)*

Comment: Thanks. I can use open or split but I am not allowed to use panda or csv or numpy....

Answer (score 0):

Using basic building blocks: open file, read line by line (and ignore header line), create new list per line and add it to an existing list (append)

```
items = list()

with open('temp.csv','r') as fp: # open the csv file for reading (will close when "with" block ends)
    header_line = fp.readline() # keep headers for future use
    for line in fp.readlines(): # go over remaining lines
        col = line.strip().split(",") # get the columns of data
        new_item = [col[0],col[1],col[3]] # keep only 1st, 2nd, 4th items in a new list, starting count from 0, since this is how lists work in python
        items.append(new_item) # add the current item to the item list

print(items)
```